Does a crossed extension with trivial Postnikov invariant admit a section?
This question is part of my effort to understand higher cohomology of groups in terms of extensions.
Recall an $n$-fold crossed extension of a group $G$ by an abelian group $K$ is an exact sequence of groups
$$1 \to K \to E_1 \to \cdots \to E_n \to G \to 1.$$
A morphism between such things is a commuting map of diagrams with the identity on $G$ and $K$. This defines a category that I will denote $\mathcal{E}^n$. We can define connected components of this category, a set $\pi_0 \mathcal{E}^n$ of equivalence classes where two $n$-fold crossed extensions are equivalent if they are connected by a zig-zag of morphisms.
It is known that $\pi_0 \mathcal{E}^n$ is in bijection with the group cohomology $H^{n+1}(G,K)$. One way to define this bijection is to think about set-theoretic sections $s:G \to E_n$ and look at the obstruction for this to be a group homomorphism, and keep doing the analog of that until we get an $n+1$ cocycle valued in $K$, which I will call the Postnikov invariant.
My question is, since we define the Postnikov invariant somewhat as the obstruction to choosing this section to be a group homomorphism, when the Postnikov invariant vanishes, does there exist a group-theoretic section?
Note that this is true for $n = 1$, which is the usual statement that if the Postnikov class of a group extension vanishes, then the extension is split.
It is also true that if the Postnikov invariant vanishes, then the crossed extension is connected by a zig-zag to the split one, which is a (twisted) product of $1 \to G \to G \to 1$ and $1 \to K \to K \to 1$, which admits a section. I am not sure I can use this zig-zag to produce a section for the original extension, however. This makes me suspect it may be false.
More generally, is there a more concrete way to characterize the equivalence classes in $\pi_0 \mathcal{E}^n$?

No. For $n>1$ you can always choose a representative with $E_n$ a free non-Abelian group, so there cannot be a section unless $G$ is free, and in that case the cohomology is trivial and all cross extensions have sections.

Aha, thank you. And in that case the crossed extension from a presentation of G admits an obvious map to 1->G->G->1 so it also obeys the theorem I quoted. Cheers.

In fact a larger family of counterexamples are of the form 1-> 1 -> F -> E -> G -> 1 (n = 2 for concreteness), where E is any non-split extension.
